# How to get the value of a user's CHECK_EXPIRATION property?

Tags: sql-server

[ALTER LOGIN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189828.aspx) allows one to change the `CHECK_EXPIRATION` property associated with an account, but how does one get the existing value of this property for an arbitrary user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this data through the [`LOGINPROPERTY()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345412.aspx) system function:

```
select loginproperty('your_login_name', 'daysuntilexpiration');
```

If you want to see if the SQL logins is subject to expiration, just check `sys.sql_logins`:

```
select name, is_expiration_checked
from sys.sql_logins;
```

**Note**:  As per [the documentation on `CHECK_EXPIRATION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189828.aspx), this only applies to SQL logins, not Windows logins.  If you need to get this expiration for Windows accounts, then I recommend you create programmatic logic (outside of SQL Server) to grab the login(s) from SQL Server, and then make AD calls to get expiration date.  [To do this with PowerShell, this seems to be a good blog post on a quick methodology](http://blogs.technet.com/b/poshchap/archive/2014/02/21/get-a-list-of-ad-users-39-password-expiry-dates.aspx).

Comment: This does not work for network logins. I will clarify the question.

Comment: @Gili `CHECK_EXPIRATION` only applies to SQL logins.  Sounds like you need to make AD/OS calls to get Windows login expirations.

Comment: @Gili No problem, glad to help!  I've edited in a quick approach to getting this for Windows users.